# Glide Placeholder caching

Tags: android, android-glide

I am just curious if Glide is caching placeholder in the size of image views that request belongs to. I mean, if I have a recycler view and  load some image URIs to image view in list items and, say, use a placeholder with size of 512x512 px for each request, will it affect the performance? Or will the placeholder cached in the given size once and then reused every time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are *right*. Glide will cash only once 512x512 image and use it every time when needed. Comparing to Picasso Glide cashes every resized image, when Picasso resizes on the fly. Glide cashing can also be configured depending on your need using methods like `diskCacheStrategy()`, `onlyRetrieveFromCache()` etc. See [this link](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html) for more information.